# Get count of items jQuery.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I am parsing XML using jQuery. I want to get the count of all the sub nodes with the given tag name.

**For example:**

```
<People>
<person name="hello'></person>
<person name="hello'></person>
<person name="hello'></person>
<person name="hello'></person>
<person name="hello'></person>
</people>
```

I use the **following jQuery Code:**

```
$(xml).find("person").each(function(){});
```

Of course the above code works, but I just want to get the count, I do not want to loop.  The reason is this: The above sample is too easy, my XML file and javascript code is a bit complex, so there is a lot of logic to figure out the xml file, and I don't want to spend code writing all that.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to get the count then use the `length` property:

```
$(xml).find("person").length;
```

- API Reference: http://api.jquery.com/length/

Comment: length is a property, not a function.

Comment: `length` is an attribute, not a method. Drop those parens.

Answer (score 1):

Or also try `size()`:

```
$(xml).find("person").size();
```

Comment: Or `.length`, which may be faster.

Comment: size() is being deprecated ...use length